How to elegantly side-output to different streams based on configuration in the processing of connecting broadcast streams and configuration streams?
After connecting Flink data streams and broadcast streams, we find that in the processElement method of the ProcessFunction, the ctx object can only perform read-only operations and cannot directly output to different streams. This design limitation restricts our ability to output data to different streams based on configuration. Why does the ctx object in processElement only support read-only operations? How can we elegantly implement the requirement to output to different streams based on configuration?
I want to be able to side-output data to different streams in the processElement method of the ProcessFunction after connecting Flink data streams and broadcast streams.

Flink supports Side Outputs from ProcessFunctions using the context.output() function which accepts an OutputTag<T> that details the type information of the object you are returning as well as the object itself as seen below:
// Example OutputTag
object Tags{
    val widgets = OutputTag("widgets", TypeInformation.of(Widget::class.java))
}

// Usage
override fun processElement(...) {
   ...
   // Output a side-output (that may differ from your current type)
   context.output(Tags.widget, element.widget)
}

If you statically define your OutputTag, you can easily share it between the operator outputting it as well as in your job graph to create a new stream of the side-outputs themselves:
// Contents outputted via collector.collect()
val exampleStream = yourPreviouslyConnectedStream
  .process(YourExampleProcessFunction())
  
// Contents outputted via context.output(Tags.widget, ...)
val widgets = exampleStream.getSideOutput(Tags.widgets)

There isn't any limits or restrictions on the number of side-outputs that can be used within a single ProcessFunction so if you need to identify multiple outputs, you can do so by just adding additional OutputTag references.

It sounds like you are probably referring to the ReadOnlyContext passed into processElement method of a BroadcastProcessFunction or KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction. That context allows you to call the output method without any restrictions. The only "read only" aspect of that context is that you cannot modify the broadcast state -- it can only be read (for reasons that are explained in the documentation).
